# How do I visit the "Marked Planet" in Community Research?

Tags: no-mans-sky

In the new Community Research mission, the Objectives read

- Make contact with the Space Anomaly (I've done that)
- Visit the marked planet

  - If necessary, user Specialist Polo's portal address data to aid interstellar travel

I'm not sure what the note means...I can go to a Space Anomaly and talk to specialist Polo, but he won't tell me anything about coordinates...he just makes his usual offer to sell me stuff.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get into space.  The game will tell you a portal has been detected.  Go to it and activate it.